# How to redirect page and then pre-fill the options with ajax data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The situation is like this:

On page1.php, there's a grid of data, each row has a view link.  Now, when I click a view link, it should redirect to another page, that would be page2.php.  On page2.php, there are 5 checkboxes and an input form (it's actually a search option/feature with a submit button).  I want to prefill those options from a data that was pulled from the db, which was based from the "ID" of the "view" link from page1.php and then show the results of the search thing based from the prefilled options.  How should I pproach this?

Here's my current code

```
   $('.view').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var userid = $('#userid').val();
       window.location = './page2.php';
       //I don't really know what to do here.
       //assuming the db table is named testtable?
       //am i just gonna use $.ajax() ?, if so,how will i extract the returned data
       // in order to prefill the options on page2.php and at the same time
       // show the result of the search based from the prefilled options?

   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need AJAX for this?

You can just set the HREF of your link to redirect to `page2.php?var=smth` and then use that value to extract info with php from the database, and populate the HTML form according to it.

Comment: but there's a submit button on page2.php, using just my imagination, if I'll do e.g page2.php?id=1 , I can only pre fill the checkboxes and input form, but it won't submit itself, correct ?, so how will I do get the search result also at the exact time the input forms were prefilled ?

Comment: I am not really sure I follow you.. You want to redirect to page2 and pre fill it with data, then you want the form to be auto-submitted and show search results on the previous page? If this is the case, then you don't really need page2. You can just attach an ajax call to the link on page1, do a search and return the results in page1 without redirecting anywhere...

Comment: i see, that's what am thinking earlier, ajax and link it. thanks